# I cannot run turbo c++ as it says can't init sdl

Tags: turbo-c++

The error message is: can't init SDL direct input device:set data format invalid parameters. I have recently tried to extract SDl to my system but could't do so

Comment: I don't think turbo c++ can even understand C++98... My advice: chose another compiler that is not so much out of date.

Comment: My question was that i couldn't open turbo c++ because it says sdl.dll missing ... All my friends are using the same version and it is working correctly in their pc's..When i copy sdl.dll  in the folder turbo c++ starts running and again stops after some days.. sir plz help me with this problem.. Can i fix this or not @StephaneRolland??

Comment: Sorry I use Linux. For free c++ compiler on windows you could try: NetBeans for c++ https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/  you could also try Microsft Visual Studio Express, or install cygwin and use gcc.

Comment: Thanks alot it work perfectly when i plugged in my Usb @Zeninwolf thanks so much... thanks alot

Comment: Thank u @StephaneRolland for giving me some others ideas. thanks alot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I have an HP hybrid with detachable keyboard base running windows 8.1 and I wanted to start brushing up my archaic programming skills.  I was able to run Turbo C4 at home, but as soon as I took my machine mobile I got the "could not init SPI" error.  When I got home it worked just fine again.  My home setup includes a USB keyboard and mouse.

After testing I was able to confirm that the turbo c4 dos based environment can't handle a touchpad.  When I plugged in my USB mouse everything started working again.  So, just get yourself a cheap USB mouse.

Comment: This doesn't actually look like the same problem at all.

Comment: It started to work perfectly after i plugged mu USB mouse..... Thanks alot for your help @ZeninWolf

Comment: Although my error message says sdl and Zenin error message says SPI but this process works perfectly... @NathanTuggy.. and thank u all of u for responding to my question..